# Coupon Collector's Problem With 24 Items

Tags: coupon-collector

So I'm pretty bad at math. At any rate, I'm trying to figure out the Coupon Collector's Problem for a set of 24. That is, how many items will I have to see if I get 1 randomly with replacement, before I've seen them all? I'm trying to see how many items I will need to see for 50% chance and for 99.9% chance. I saw something about n(log(n)), but I'm not quite sure what this gives me. Thanks!

Comment: An advice : as it is a **very well documented problem** (hundreds of web sites...), why don't you look first by yourself and come back, saying "I have seen this method/this result etc... on such and such  site, but I don't understand such and such..."

Comment: The [Erdős and Rényi limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations), $\operatorname{P}(T < n\log n + cn) \to e^{-e^{-c}}, \ \  \text{as}  \ n \to \infty$ used as an approximation with $n=24$, seems to give close to the correct answer for the median and about $5$ away for $99.9\%$